# click box for radio button

Tags: html

When you hover over and `select` div becomes green and you click somewhere in green div then `radio button` should be clicked/selected also, how to do that?

```css
.select {
color: black;
background-color: blue
}

.select:hover {
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="select"><input type="radio" class='click' value="1,000,000" /> 1,000,000</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use label instead of div

```
<label class="select"><input type="radio" class='click' value="1,000,000" /> 1,000,000</label>
```